# PHP Array: rename key and update values from a given key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array:

```
$array = Array(
      [0] => Array(
                  [Branch] => 'Toyota',
                  [Country] => 'Jpn',
                  [id] => 'jp01'
      )
      [1] => Array(
                  [Branch] => 'Nissan',
                  [Country] => 'Jpn',
                  [id] => 'jp05'
      )
      [2] => Array(
                  [Branch] => 'Honda',
                  [Country] => 'Jpn',
                  [id] => 'jp20'
      ) )
```

What I want to do is:
1 - Change the key **`Branch`** to **`Brand`**, but without moving it to the end or the array.
2 - Update all the values to the key Country, changing **`Jpn`** to **`Japan`**

The result should be like this:

```
$array = Array(
      [0] => Array(
                  [Brand] => 'Toyota',
                  [Country] => 'Japan',
                  [id] => 'jp01'
      )
      [1] => Array(
                  [Brand] => 'Nissan',
                  [Country] => 'Japan',
                  [id] => 'jp05'
      )
      [2] => Array(
                  [Brand] => 'Honda',
                  [Country] => 'Japan',
                  [id] => 'jp20'
      ) )
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Could 'Country' contain values other than 'Jpn'?

Comment: Yes, 'Country' can be any string, but when updating, all will be changed to only one value

Answer (score 3):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $ar){
    $newArray[] = array(
       'Brand' => $ar['Branch'],
       'Country' => 'Japan',
       'id' => $ar['id']
    )
}
$array = $newArray;
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me just how stupid I am. "It's simple: Don't change the key, just create a new array and replace the old one."

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    $branch = $item['Branch'];
    array_unshift($item, array("Brand"=>$branch));
    unset($item['Branch']);
    $item['Country'] = 'Japan'; 
}
```

Haven't tested it..

Comment: If it works, that is a cool solution. Especially using an ampersand for the items so you can change the array without the need of the key. Very clever!

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $data)
{
$data['Brand'] = $data['Branch'];
$data['Country'] = 'Japan';
unset($data['Branch']);
$array[$key] = $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: That'll put the `Brand` key at the end of the array.

Comment: So what? Keys in associative arrays should have no explicit order.

Comment: This will also update every 'Country' element to null, or possibly the empty string.  $data['Japan'] does not exist.

Comment: hmm, that will.. But that shouldn't really matter in case of associative arrays.

Comment: @haydenmuhl: That was a typo.

Comment: In PHP, hashtables (which are arrays) are ordered. You never lose the order of an array/hashtable in PHP. It's the only language I'm aware of that works this way, and implementation experts will bash PHP for it, because it's really not a good idea from a performance perspective... except PHP is still ridiculously fast so the standard attitude is to simply not care. ;)

And lots of projects make use of this feature of PHP so they can't really change it now without problems.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
<?php
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
  $array[$k]['Brand'] = $array[$k]['Branch'];
  unset($array[$k]['Branch'];
  if($array[$k]['Country'] == 'Jpn') {
    $array[$k]['Country'] = 'Japan';
  }
}
?>
```

There are probably clever array functions that could do it, too, but this will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $subArray){
    foreach($subArray as $subkey => $value)
        if($value === 'Jpn') $subArray[$subkey] = 'Japan';
    $array[$key] = $subArray;
}


foreach($array as $key => $subArray){
    $subArray = array_flip($subArray);
    foreach($subArray as $subkey => $value)
        if($value === 'Branch') $subArray[$subkey] = 'Brand';
    $subArray = array_flip($subArray);
    $array[$key] = $subArray;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Brand] => Toyota [Country] => Japan [id] => jp01 ) [1] => Array ( [Brand] => Nissan [Country] => Japan [id] => jp05 ) [2] => Array ( [Brand] => Honda [Country] => Japan [id] => jp20 ) )
```